# Building Qemu - unknown target name 'arm-softmmu'

Tags: linux, qemu

I'm following this Github tutorial: https://jsandler18.github.io/tutorial/dev-env.html

I'm trying to learn a bit about making an operating system and I thought I would use my Raspberry Pi. I'm trying to compile Qemu to simulate ARM but I get this error when I try to do configure:

`ERROR: Unknown target name 'arm-softmmu'`

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and I have `build-essentials` installed.

Comment: It is probably worth trying to post an issue: https://github.com/jsandler18/jsandler18.github.io/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out I was missing some dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install git-email
sudo apt-get install libaio-dev libbluetooth-dev libbrlapi-dev libbz2-dev
sudo apt-get install libcap-dev libcap-ng-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libgtk-3-dev
sudo apt-get install libibverbs-dev libjpeg8-dev libncurses5-dev libnuma-dev
sudo apt-get install librbd-dev librdmacm-dev
sudo apt-get install libsasl2-dev libsdl1.2-dev libseccomp-dev libsnappy-dev libssh2-1-dev
sudo apt-get install libvde-dev libvdeplug-dev libvte-2.90-dev libxen-dev liblzo2-dev
sudo apt-get install valgrind xfslibs-dev
sudo apt-get install libnfs-dev libiscsi-dev
```

I got them off of this website: https://wiki.qemu.org/Hosts/Linux

Comment: Please state which dependencies, so someone finding this post has a lead to the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed. I don't know which exact dependencies I needed though, I installed all of them at the time.

Comment: a piece of advise, never install dependecies that you don't need as it may lead to problems